# Flask: How to pipe a file from requests.get()?

Tags: python, flask

I have a flask server, and in a GET request, I want to download a file from another server then respond to the client. The code is like:

```py
import requests
from flask import send_file

def get(self, report_id):
    url = origin + '/reports/sastScan/' + report_id
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    return send_file(<something correct here>, attachment_filename='report.pdf')
```

Do I need to write the `r.content` into a file then give it to `send_file`, or I can use other functions rather than `send_file`, or I can use some other attributes from `response`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one: wrap the response as `BytesIO` and send it use `send_file`

```py
from io import BytesIO


def get(self, report_id):
    url = origin + '/reports/sastScan/' + report_id

    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, allow_redirects=True)
    # Reencode r.content with utf-8. Otherwise, you'd better set encoding
    # manually in mimetype
    file_obj = BytesIO(r.text.encode('utf-8'))

    # file_obj is not a real file obj. We have to 
    # provide `filename` or `attachment_filename` explicitly
    return send_file(
        file_obj, 
        attachment_filename='report.pdf', 
        mimetype="Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=utf-8"
    )
```

Points:

- `BytesIO` is not a real file, since `BytesIO` doesn't have `.name` property, we have to provide `filename` or `attachment_filename` explicitly in `send_file()`
- Explicit **charset** is preferred to be provided in `send_file()`

In case the **response is not text**. The following may be better

```
def get(self, report_id):
    url = origin + '/reports/sastScan/' + report_id
    file_obj = BytesIO(r.content)

    return send_file(
        file_obj, 
        attachment_filename='report.pdf', 
        mimetype=f"Content-Type: application/pdf; charset={r.encoding}"
    )
```